# Spring Data JPA Java Config HibernatePersistence.class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

HibernatePersistence.class is deprecated. What should be the alternative for this code?

```
import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
@Bean  
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {  
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();  
                entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());  
                entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);  
                entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));  

                entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());  

                return entityManagerFactoryBean;  
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be.

```
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
```

As the provider

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/

Comment: that's my current provider.

Comment: And where in the api said that it is deprecated, why version of hibernate are you usgin _

Comment: <hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>

Comment: Update in my answer, it should be the jpa package according to the documentation, very weird that in final version hibernate deprecate it . Try a shoot using the org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

Comment: Hey.. what is the xml version of above LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. I want to know how I can set persistence provider using xml inside my LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly alright. You don't need any alternative solutions. The issue is because of you missed the hibernate entity manager .jar library [or hibernate-entitymanager maven dependency if your using maven as your project builder]. Add hibernate-entitymanager maven dependency inside your pom file and update your project. It's work fine.

Thank you.
Mohamed Nashath.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I've fixed it by adding following dependency to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

plus

`import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;`